# how to consume kwargs from flask in jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, keyword-argument

From a jinja html file, I want to consume & print the `kwargs` passed from python/flask. I pass variables into flask `render_template`, however, I can't figure out how to get the `kwargs` from jinja.  This is a minimal flask example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)    
@app.route("/foo", methods=['POST'])
def foo():
    return render_template("mypage.html", alpha=request.form.get('alpha'),
            beta=request.form.get('beta'))
```

This is the jinja html file `mypage.html`:

```
<html><body><ul>
    {% for k, v in kwargs.items() %}
        <li>{{ k }}{{ v }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul></body></html>
```

This is the error when I try to post to the page:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'kwargs' is undefined
```

Very sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't find this question/answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your program needs to match template's kwargs:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)    
@app.route("/foo", methods=['POST'])
def foo():
    kwargs = {'alpha': request.form.get('alpha'),
              'beta': request.form.get('beta'),
             }
    return render_template("mypage.html", kwargs=kwargs)
```